# Running Django tutorial example with mod_wsgi?

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I installed  wsgi (mod_wsgi), and could run the simple application by calling http://localhost/myapp.

```
WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /Library/WebServer/Documents/wsgi/scripts/myapp.wsgi
```

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World! WSGI working perfectly!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

How can I run django example?

I found [this example](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/) that has the simple example.

```
import os
import sys

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'my.settings' # ???

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

```
mysite/
    __init__.py
    manage.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
```

Django generated the three python files, and I see a settings.py that has setup info.
The project is in '/ABC/DEF/mysite' directory.

I modified the code as follows, and named it myapp.wsgi.

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/ABC/DEF/mysite') 
sys.path.append('/ABC/DEF')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Even though I could run the original django example from [the tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) that uses "python manage.py runserver 8080", I got an error running the modified example with mod_wsgi.

The apache2/log file has the following.

```
[Wed Nov 24 09:02:41 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named mysite.settings
```

As far as I know, the directory/project name is mysite, and it has the settings.py. And the directory is in the sys.path. So, I don't know why mysite.settings is not found.

What's wrong with my myapp.wsgi?

### SOLVED

The following code works fine.
And the other thing that I modified was the django project should not be in my home directory, when I moved the project to www doc directory, everything works fine.

```
import os
import sys

mysite = 'SOMEWEHRE/django'
if mysite not in sys.path:sys.path.insert(0,mysite)
mysite = 'SOMEWEHRE/scripts'
if mysite not in sys.path:sys.path.insert(0,mysite)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Comment: "I don't setup the mysite.settings"?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams : I should have written I didn't know how to setup the settings.

Comment: mysite.settings refers to YourProjectName.settings. It's how Python gets what's in your settings.py file.

Comment: please post solution as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is add either the project directory or the directory the project is in to `sys.path`, and then point the settings to `mysite.settings` if you've done the latter.

**EDIT:**

["Django settings"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/)

**EDIT 2:**

[How to set the Django settings module](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/)

**EDIT 3:**

The settings module should be the module, not the filename. And if it's `'settings'` then you don't need to set it.

Comment: Could you give me an example how to 'point the settings to mysite.settings'? I added to my OP.