# Does Django or mod_wsgi modify sys.path when it's running?

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I setup mod_wsgi, and checked it works fine.
I also came up with simple django project, and also checked it works fine with the following command

```
django-admin.py runserver --settings=mysite.settings
```

However, when I run the following wsgi,

```
import os
import sys

mysite = '/Users/smcho/Desktop/django/mysite'
if mysite not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0,'/Users/smcho/Desktop/django/mysite')
django = '/Users/smcho/Desktop/django'
if django not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0,'/Users/smcho/Desktop/django')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I got this error.

```
[Wed Nov 24 10:36:45 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named mysite.settings
```

By running following python code with mod_wsgi, I learned that "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages" is in sys.path.

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World! WSGI working perfectly!\n'*10
    for i in sys.path:
        output += str(i) + '\n'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

And this is the sys.path that I got. It doesn't have the path from PYTHONPATH.

```
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/ply-3.3-py2.6.egg
...
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/nose-0.11.4-py2.6.egg
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python26.zip
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-old
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages 
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/wx-2.8-mac-unicode
```

So, I copied 'mysite' django project to '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages', and now it works OK.

What's wrong with this? It's very likely that even though I added my django project directory to sys.path, django doesn't know (or disregards) this path and the paths from PYTHONPATH environment variable.

```
    sys.path.insert(0,'/Users/smcho/Desktop/django/mysite')
    sys.path.insert(0,'/Users/smcho/Desktop/django')
```

Does Django modifies sys.path when it's running? If so, how to prevent this? If not, why Django doesn't know about my appened path?

This is the system that I'm using.

```
OS : Mac OS X 10.6.5
Python : 2.6.1
Django : 1.2.3
```

### SOLVED

Please refer to my other [PO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263001/running-django-tutorial-example-with-mod-wsgi). In short, I moved my django project to www doc directory that is accessible from web, everything's OK.

Answer (score 1):

You only check that '/Users/smcho/Desktop/django/mysite' is in `sys.path`, but if not you add that and the '/Users/smcho/Desktop/django'. To import `mysite.settings`, Python needs the latter, not the former. So you should be sure to add that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I checked and those two paths are added to the sys.path, but without success. My question is why Django doesn't know about my added path.