# Remove installed Python 3.5 from Mac Os X global path

Tags: python, macos, osx-elcapitan

I have recently installed the "official" Python 3.5 on Mac Os X (El Capitan). During this installation, Python changes the global path to include `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin` (this can be seen using for instance `/usr/libexec/path_helper`).

However, I am unable to understand where this "set" is done (there is nothing nor in `/etc/paths` neither in `/etc/paths.d`). I would like to remove this entry from the global path (without removing the installation itself because it can be always useful).

Comment: Have you checked your `.bash_profile`?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your input. Actually I am using zsh but there is nothing in shell config files (both in user/system zshrc and basic). I believe there must be something more general (like the /etc/paths.d or the /etc/paths) but I may be missing something obvious.

Comment: this may be helpfull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271494/what-sets-up-sys-path-with-python-and-when

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have got the same issue. After a SUPER LONG search I found this file: `"~/.zprofile"`. Check within this file and you will find the following code:

```css
# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The original version is saved in .zprofile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Just remove this code and save the file.

Comment: check this: https://superuser.com/questions/866683/iterm-zsh-not-reading-bashrc-or-bash-profile

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar output when running:

> echo $PATH

Standard out-put result:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin

The following sequence of steps solved the issue for me using zsh (macOS Big Sur Version 11.1)

> cd /Users/JohnDoe

> vim .zprofile

Remove the following PATH settings and save the file:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.8
#The original version is saved in .zprofile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.9
# The original version is saved in .zprofile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Refresh zsh profile from the users home directory:

> source .zshrc

Check your work:

> echo $PATH

Standard out-put result:

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin

Answer (score 0):

To remove python 3.5 from your mac try below command

```
cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
sudo rm -rf 3.5
```