# Python throws: Invalid -W option ignored: invalid module name: 'yaml'

Tags: python, file, debugging, config

Installed python from scratch on computer and still throws an error anytime a .py file is being used whether it's my short script 'print('aa')' or some other utility (Jenkins Job Builder) which uses python script underneath dropping this line: `Invalid -W option ignored: invalid module name: 'yaml'` every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module `yaml` is provided by `PyYAML` package, so do a 
`pip install PyYAML`.

However, look at your `setup.py`, dependencies should be configured properly and `PyYAML` should be installed as a dependency.

Comment: that's the issue - I've already installed the ```pip install PyYAML```  -> ```Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML in /Users/<user>/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (3.13)```

Comment: I've search for every file in directory - there is not setup.py with PyYAML inside ```grep --include=setup.py -nrw /Users/<user>/Library/Python -e "PyYAML"```

Comment: I've found 2 issues on this (including this one) and the other refers to a bug report.  I have a versIon of Python which is post-fix:  I'm very inclined to believe something old has managed to survive, much to our consternation.

Comment: Ugh.  Python's warning system is just awful. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495641/filtering-based-on-custom-warning-categories